# Using WITH condition, but code seems to be throwing syntax error, whats wrong?

Tags: sql

```
with values as (select * from A)
        select * from values;
```

Comment: what is the error? which dbms (mysql, tsql, postgresql, oracle)?

Answer (score 1):

reserve word can not you use without double quote

```
with "values" as (select * from A)
        select * from "values";
```

Answer (score 0):

`values` is a reserved keyword, you need double quotes if you really want to use it as an identifier.

```
with "values" as (
   select * 
   from a
)
select *
from "values";
```

Using double quotes for identifiers is standard SQL, however some DBMS ignore the standard and use other characters instead.

Online example: https://rextester.com/WNNXO58854